# Whats mean instance * hour in azure

Tags: azure

Hi I need to buy a subscription in azure with two DB and 1 Basic App. 
Anyway I don't understand what stand for instance * hours. 
I wrote an B2B site in aspnet that has to be run in this subscripotion.

How can I calculate or know how many instances I need?
And how do you calculate the hours for instance? 
Is possible set it scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, there are 4 question in this question.

Well, `instance * hours` means you will have to pay X of some currency for every hour or every instance working. So 1 instance working for 20 hours = 20 hours billed, 5 instances working for 20 hours = 100 hours billed.

Hours are calculated pretty straight forward, once you've created App Service Plan you are being billed constantly, until you delete it.

Yes, [WebApp's are scalable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devschool/2015/05/24/azure-how-to-auto-scale-your-web-apps-web-sites/). And for the `How can I calculate or know how many instances I need?` we can't help you. It depends on your load. You would need to do some performance testing emulating actual load.

Also, check out the [pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=app-service).

edit in Instances: So when you create a WebApp it has 1 instance initially. Instance is a VM hosting IIS that is hosting your WebApp. When you scale it, you create additional instances (VM's) that host additional IIS instances that host copies of your WebApp.

Comment: thanks buta what instance stand for? If i need to do complex operation i need more ram or cpu... why i need more instance?

Comment: so i need more than one instance only when i have a lot of visitor in my site and the VM hosting become slow or the site in no more accessible. Right?

Comment: exactly, if the performance is bad, you would need another instance (or scale this instance, to have more CPU\RAM). Also, if this answers your question, you should mark it as answer ;)